# Print an array in the form of a grid in Java

Tags: java

How would I print an array in the form of a grid in Java? The arrays in the code below are the row and column size but anytime I enter 6 random variables the program outputs the numbers 1-6 in a grid.

e.g i enter the numbers - 1 16 13 18 14 23

i would expect it to print:

```
 1 18
16 14
13 23
```

but instead i get

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

this is the code I'm working with

```
public void printCardAsGrid(String numbers) {
        String[] gridNumbers = numbers.split(" ");
        int [] gridNum = new int[gridNumbers.length];
        for (int x = 0; x < gridNumbers.length; x++){
            gridNum[x] = Integer.parseInt(gridNumbers[x]);

    


int[][] cardGrid = new int[currentRowSize][currentColumnSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < currentRowSize; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < currentColumnSize; j++) {
                    cardGrid[i][j] = gridNum[i];
                    i += currentRowSize;
                }
            }
            for (int[] gridInt : cardGrid) {
                for (int anInt : gridInt) {
                    if (anInt < 10){
                        System.out.printf(" " + anInt + " ");
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.printf(anInt + " ");
                    }
    
                }
                System.out.println();
```

Comment: i forgot to add the initalization for 'currentRowSize' and currentColumnSize'

Comment: You can edit your question and fix what you missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in populating `cardGrid`. You are using `i` in the for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < currentRowSize; i++) {
```

with the condition `i < currentRowSize`, but at the same time you are incrementing it with

```
i += currentRowSize;
```

You want to use `i` as the index for `cardGrid` and `gridNum`. Try using it only for `cardGrid` and calculate the index for `gridNum` with `i`,`j` and `currentRowSize`. Populating `cardGrid` would then look like this:

```
int currentRowSize = 3;
int currentColumnSize = 2;

int[][] cardGrid = new int[currentRowSize][currentColumnSize];

for (int i = 0; i < currentRowSize; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < currentColumnSize; j++) {
        cardGrid[i][j] = gridNum[j * currentRowSize + i];
    }
}
```